# Datatables,Export to excel with dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tried to export but getting all options in excel file. is there any way to get only selected items instead of all dropdown options?

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'surname' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'office' },
            { data: 'salary' }
        ],
        buttons: [         
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            }
        ]
    } );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87hpvegu/)

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/select.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following export options:

```
exportOptions: {
  format: {
    body: function ( inner, rowidx, colidx, node ) {
      if ($(node).children("select").length > 0) {
        // we are in a cell containing a "select" drop-down - so, get it:
        var selectNode = node.firstElementChild;
        var txt = selectNode.options[selectNode.selectedIndex].value;
        //var txt = selectNode.options[selectNode.selectedIndex].text;
        return txt;
      } else {
        return inner; // the standard cell contents
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This uses JavaScript to manipulate the `node` provided by the `body` function.

In this specific case, it returns the *value* associated with the selected drop-down option. So, for example, if you have this:

```
<option value="some_value">Some Value</option>
```

then the spreadsheet will contain "some_value" and not "Some Value".

If you want the displayed text ("Some Value"), then use the commented-out line in the above code instead. But in that case you would need some extra logic to replace the placeholder text "Select Report" with a blank string.

---

For some reason, I was not able to use a jQuery selector here. I wanted to use `option :selected` but I was not able to get that to work - not sure why. But the pure JavaScript approach (above) did work.

Comment: you sir/madam are a lifesaver.