# Export Icon data instead of empty data using jquery datatables

Tags: .net, user-interface, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery datatable. My UI table has got icons in one of it's columns. When I click download, it downloads the csv file. But in place of icons, it is displaying empty cell. But I want the text of that icon to be displayed there. I tried the below URL.

I tried to show my scenario in the below link (but here it is not showing the icon though, but it has got the title in the tag which has to be in the excel file under the Icon header).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ttse23/ruvvb2rc/

**HTML**

```
<h1>Print test</h1>
<div class="data-table-container">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered data-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-right">No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td>Name 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-right">2</td>
        <td>Name 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="text-center">footer text</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('table.data-table').DataTable({
  paging: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 'no-sort',
    orderable: false
  }],
  dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-6"Bl><"col-sm-6"f>>' +
    '<"row"<"col-sm-12"<"table-responsive"tr>>>' +
    '<"row"<"col-sm-5"i><"col-sm-7"p>>',
  fixedHeader: {
    header: true
  },
  buttons: {
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'excel',
      text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Export to Excel',
      title: $('h1').text(),
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
            page: 'current'
        }
      },
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
    }, {
      extend: 'pdf',
      text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF',
      title: $('h1').text(),
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
            page: 'applied'
        }
      },
      footer: true
    }],
    
    dom: {
      
      container: {
        className: 'dt-buttons'
      },
      button: {
        className: 'btn btn-default'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Can someone help me out with this? I tried `stripHtml` as well. But still no luck.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us the relevant (minimal) code in the question itself - especially since the Fiddle does not show an example of an icon.

Comment: Having said that, you can use the `body` function in your `exportOptions` option to access the text you want to export. You can see a similar example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66875847/datatables-export-to-excel-with-dropdown-values/66876678#66876678). In that case the code is accessing a selected value from a drop-down list. But you can access whatever attribute you need using the JavaScript `getAttribute()` function.